# Как обойти ограничение в 50 МБ на отправку видео через Telegram бота в telebot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot, python-telegram-bot

Бот должен загружать видео на сервер, после действия пользователя и отправить его пользователю, но столкнулся с ошибкой из-за превышения лимита. Я видел руководство, где говорится о том, как обойти это ограничение с использованием file_id для больших файлов. Как можно реализовать это на практике?

```
try:
    with yt_dlp.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        ydl.download([link])

        if os.path.exists(video_path):
            video_file = open(video_path, 'rb')
            bot.delete_message(callback_query.message.chat.id, callback_query.message.id)
            bot.send_video(callback_query.message.chat.id, video_file)
            video_file.close()
except yt_dlp.utils.DownloadError as e:
    print(f"DownloadError: {e}")
    bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id, text='Доступ к видео ограничен')
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Exception: {e}")
    bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id, text='Не удалось скачать видео')
finally:
    if os.path.exists(video_path):
        os.remove(video_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

Что бы отправить файлы большого размера(больше 50 мб):

0. Останавливаем бота.
1. Сами отправляем боту нужный файл большого размера, через сообщения.
2. После загрузки файла вбиваем в браузер **https://api.telegram.org/bot<ваш_токен>/getUpdates**
3. Ищем словарь `"document"`
4. Нас интересует строка формата `"file_id":"BQACAgIAAxkBAAOnZa_KdOYkK6AvlXhetbUnXG-AiWcAAuc4AAIjWYFJUokbePqOh840BA"` - копируем `id` файла.

```
max_size_description = "big file" 
file ='BQACAgIAAxkBAAOnZa_KdOYkK6AvlXhetbUnXG-AiWcAAuc4AAIjWYFJUokbePqOh840BA'
bot.send_document(chat_id=chat_id, document=file, caption=max_size_description)
```

Через Telebot:

```
import telebot

TOKEN = 'Token'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['document', 'video', 'audio', 'photo'])
def handle_files(message):
    # Получаем ID файла
    file_id = None

    if message.document:
        file_id = message.document.file_id
    elif message.video:
        file_id = message.video.file_id
    elif message.audio:
        file_id = message.audio.file_id
    elif message.photo:
        file_id = message.photo[0].file_id

    if file_id:
        print(f"File ID: {file_id}")
        # Отправляем ответом полученный file_id
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"File ID: {file_id}")
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Error file_id")

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Пользователь нажимает на кнопку для загрузки видео на сервер. Как нам автоматически определить file_id загруженного видео? Нам нужно, чтобы процесс был автоматизирован и file_id зависел от конкретного видео, которое загружает пользователь. Например, если пользователь загружает видео с YouTube, мы хотим отправить его без ограничений. Как это сделать?

Comment: @Алексей дополнил ответ.

Comment: извиняюсь, ошибся. У нас производится скачивание видео по представленной ссылке, после скачивания у нас видео находится на сервере и до отправки судя по всему мы должны определить его file_id, чтоб скинуть видео > 50 МБ?

Comment: @Алексей как вижу алгоритм я: загружаете в бота свои файлы, сохраняете полученные id в бд или скажем файл, по необходимости отправляете нужное видео зная его id. Так что если хотите обойти кап 50 мб, то вам сперва нужно ваши файлы предварительно загрузить в телеграмм. Или подымайте свой локальный апи сервер как уже писали ниже, но это уже уходит за рамки вашего вопроса.

Answer (score 0):

`file_id` присваивается файлу со стороны Telegram, который был загружен к ним на сервера. Когда пользователь отправляет файл боту, ему присваивается file_id. В этом случае, это файл бот может пересылать неограниченные количество раз и без лимитов по размеру файла.

Но если у вас происходит загрузка файла на сервер и отправка его с сервера ботом, таким образом лимиты на размер файла обойти не получится.

Телеграм же предлагает решение снятия этих лимитов - [Using a Local Bot API Server](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#using-a-local-bot-api-server)

> If you switch to a local Bot API server, your bot will be able to:
>
> Download files without a size limit. Upload files up to 2000 MB.
> Upload files using their local path and the file URI scheme. Use an
> HTTP URL for the webhook. Use any local IP address for the webhook.
> Use any port for the webhook. Set max_webhook_connections up to
> 100000. Receive the absolute local path as a value of the file_path field without the need to download the file after a getFile request.

Устанавливаете local Bot API и все, у вас не будет ограничений на размер загружаемого и отправляемого файла